# How to load multiple files (in multiple subdirectories) into vim buffers?

Tags: vim

My directory structure is like this:

```
inc/abc/xyz.hpp ...
inc/def/hij.hpp ...
```

**I would effectively like to load all my hpp files into vim buffers for editing.**

Unfortunately,

```
vim inc/*/*.hpp
```

didn't work as I expected (vim thought that it had to create a new * directory).

I currently have 258 header files so I need an efficient way to pull all of them up into vim at once.  Thx.

Answer (score 4):

nm, I seemed to have found the answer:

```
:args inc/*/*.hpp
```

seems to work from inside vim.

Answer (score 2):

`vim inc/*/*.hpp` should work. If it doesn't then the problem is with the shell you're using.